# The Features module and blocks on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, migration, drupal-blocks

I am trying to implement the Features module on one of my Drupal 7 sites for managing blocks. I have a couple questions though. 1st, when you create a new feature on the source site, do you then take that newly created feature and put it in your modules directory and enable it on the source server AND the destination server or JUST the destination server?

Also, I'm wondering how it works when you are trying to manage blocks with a test server and a live server when the live server is a clone of test. In other words we create a test server, construct our site including content and blocks and when it's finished we clone test to live. Then we install the features module on test and create a feature that contains ALL of our custom blocks. When I did this though and moved that feature to the live server and enabled it, it was immediately in an overridden state. Are features only meant for moving NEW blocks from one site to another and not meant to manage blocks that already exist on BOTH servers? Should I create the feature containing all the blocks on the test server and then delete the blocks on the live server and THEN enable the feature on live which would populate the blocks on live. I'm just not sure if I'm missing something or going about this the wrong way.

THANKS

UPDATE: OK, I'm pulling my hair out over here. Again, so I have two sites a source and a destination. The destination was is an exact clone of the source. I have three blocks on both sites that I would like to manage via features. SO, on the source site, I decided to test with just ONE block first. I first edited the block so it would be different than the one on the destination site. I then created the feature including the block and block settings (by the way I'm using Features Extra to accomplish this) and then I place the feature on the destination site and when I activate the feature, the feature is actually NOT in an overridden state and the changes that I made to the block on the source site, show up on the destination site no problem. HOWEVER, if I try to add the other two blocks now to this feature on the source site and recreate it and export it out to the destination site, the feature on the destination site is now in an overridden state which is fine, but no matter how many times I "Revert" the feature to take the blocks out of the dB and into code, it will NOT get out of an overridden state. I have flushed the cache, disabled the feature and re-enabled, and tried reverting and it is stuck as overridden and I do not see the changes to the other two blocks that I made. I then thought maybe it's because I am doing three blocks at once. I then took JUST block number two by itself and created a feature for it and put it on the destination site and it gets stuck in overridden status. Same goes for block number 3. Block number one by itself is fine and does not get stuck in overridden status. It's just block number 2 and three. As far as I can tell all three blocks were created the same exact way and do not have any different settings as far as roles, pages etc. I am stumped on this one for sure.

Comment: First thing, you need to enable feature in which site you want to use that functionality. IF you want on only destination than no need to put on source.
Second one is features already overridden. this is because that functionality in DB and features both places. so you need to revert feature, so Now db changes will be overridden by features(code). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please see update to my original post. I am stuck in an overridden state. ARG

Comment: Feature module has a good documentation! It explains all the aspects of 'features' in details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment doesn't allow this much log post, so posting as answer.

I can't say much without having exact problem. But This is how features works. You have to do changes in a source site. then create feature of that changes. Now On destination site you have to enable that feature. If you already have that changes in destination site, than feature will be overridden, you revert it and get changes.

As you saying you added two other blocks in feature, but you didn't change anything in those blocks, so they are already in destination site. that why features in overridden state. when you revert It does changes, but sometime it doesn't changes state on (admin/structure/features/).

I don't know your exact requirement, but I think you should change *do changes* in source site and then pick them in feature and enable on destination site.

Comment: Crazyrohila, thanks for your help on this. So I decided to start over and completely get rid of my feature on BOTH sites, cleared caches, ran cron, started over. I then edited all three blocks on my source site so they are drastically different than what is on the destination site. I then created a new feature that contained all three blocks and their settings. I moved the feature to the destination site, enabled and it is overridden and when I try to revert, it remains stuck as overridden no matter what and the changes to the blocks do not show up. I'm starting to think this really is a bug.

Comment: I have even tried using the latest dev versions of both Features and Features Extra.

Comment: Your changes reflected or not on destination site?

Comment: Use [Diff module](http://drupal.org/project/diff) to see what changes are there in overridden feature.

Comment: yes, You are right Its shows overridden after reverting, but changes reflected. Its state doesn't changes but it works. I use diff module to see overridden changes, but it not showing same. So Revert features works as it should, but state still remains overridden.

Comment: @ErichH. You can remove that state by updating feature. Run this command `drush fu <feature_name>`.

So the complete workflow would be, you do changes in source site. then create feature and enable in destination site. feature will show overridden, so revert it. The changes should be reflected. Now update this feature, so It will come in default state. If this helps you tell me I will update new answer, so It can help someone else.

Comment: THANKS. That did actually work. So I am still having issues with two blocks not updating correctly. I have three blocks total and only one is correctly updating, but I think that must be something on my end. I will do more testing, but doing what you said as far as reverting the features DID make the changes show for the one block, but still showed overridden so I ran the drush command you gave and that put the state back to default, so I think we are good. I will figure out what's wrong with the other two blocks on my own. THANKS!!!!

Comment: OK I wanted to give one last update. I figured out my issue regarding the two blocks that would not update. It turns out I forgot to give them the matching "machine name" on the destination site. There was a machine name on the source site, but not the destination site. As soon as I had machine names on both sites, the overridden issue actually went away completely. All I had to do was flush the cache when I updated the feature in the directory and the changes showed up and the state was in default. THANKS for all your help.

Comment: Ohh man!! I was thinking about that, but I thought you know this so It would be silly to ask this. You told me you have same blocks on both site. that's why I didn't ask. I could have save your time. But Its nice, You figured it out by yourself. :) cheers.